# Heroku: Find out which folder is the one that is live

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Imagine i have two folders, folderA and folderB, and inside them is a similar, but not exactly same application.

Matter of fact, it was an app in folderA, that from my poor version control skills, i copied to folderB and slightly modified it.

I have a test Heroku application that is live and existed in one of these two folders.

The problem is, i don't know if the app that is live, existed on folderA or folderB.

Is there a command to find out?
modded

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to use `git remote` and `git diff` to see the differences? Going by your words, you created folderB out of folderA and made some modifications to folderB. So, a `git diff` should only show differences or changes in folderB alone as long as folderA remains untouched..

To determine whether the app is live or not, you would need to look into Heroku Dashboard and `git remote show heroku` on the respective folders IMO. You can find out the app name from the fetch and push urls.

If you want to see what exactly is deployed in heroku, you can run `heroku run bash` which would basically help you figure out or guess the code deployed there.

Comment: I run 'heroku run bash' on both folders, and figured out the folder which has been uploaded to my Heroku app. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that the problem got resolved. Happy coding!